# Subtracting the amount is calculated incorrectly

Tags: angular

I have  values ​​`cost` and `quantity` in  array. And in this array there is a button that, when clicked, will decrease by 1 unit  value  `quantity`. And accordingly,  `сost` should also decrease depending cost of one unit in value  quantity.

But the result is displayed incorrectly.

**ts**:

```
  public price = 0;

  removeItem(id: number) {
    this.order.list = this.order.list.map(o => o.order_id === id && o.quantity > 1 ? { ...o, quantity: o.quantity - 1 } : o);
    this.price = this.order.list.reduce((total, item) => {
      return total += this.price - item.cost
    }, 0)
  }
```

**html**:

```
<mat-list *ngFor="let item of order.list">
    <mat-list-item>
        <div mat-line>
            {{item.name}}
        </div>
        <div mat-line>
            <button mat-mini-fab class="my-fab" color="accent" (click)="removeItem(item.order_id)">
                <mat-icon>
                    remove
                </mat-icon>
            </button>
            <span> {{item.quantity}}</span>
            <span>{{item.cost}}</span>
        </div>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</mat-list>
<span>
    {{price}}
</span>
```

Comment: "But the result is displayed incorrectly.": what exactly happens and what did you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm right then Price calculate function be like below:

```
this.price = this.order.list.reduce((total, item) => {
   return total + item.cost * item.quantity
}, 0)
```